# Set styling from parent component (props) and from component itself react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styles, native

is it possible to set some styling properties from the parent as props and some styling properties from the component itself?

Here is my component:

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class BackgroundMar extends Component {

render(){
    return (
        <View style={[styles.viewStyle]}>
            <Text>{this.props.test}</Text>
        </View>
    )
    }
};

var styles = {
viewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: props.color
}
};

export default BackgroundMar;
```

And here is my parent:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import BackgroundMar from "./components/BackgroundMar";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <BackgroundMar
        test={'aaa'}
        color={'#ff2044'}
    />
    );
  }
};

});
```

I would like to set only the backgroundColor from the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found the solution.
On the parent:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
    <BackgroundMar
        test={'#52a03f'}
    />
);
}
};
```

On the component itself:

```
class BackgroundMar extends Component {

render(){
    return (
        <View style={[styles.viewStyle, { backgroundColor: this.props.test}]}>
            <Text>{this.props.test}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
};

var styles = {
viewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
}
};
```

Comment: you did the same thing, what i wanted to explain, good, like how to add styles dynamically, use cases differ from project to project :)

Comment: oh ok sorry, I misunderstood you then. Thanks for you help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

First send styles from parent as object... ex ..

```
style={{color:"#abcd"}}
```

then inside the child component. add that to style array

```
<View style={this.props.style ? [styles.viewStyle, this.props.style] : 
  [styles.viewStyle]}>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I cannot pass an object like this.
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <BackgroundMar
            test={'aaa'}
            style={color:'#ff2044'}
        />
    );
  }
};

I have 'Error while reading multipart response'